# What does crunchPngs mean in Android buildTypes?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

As the change log of [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html), we have a new buildTypes property called `crunchPngs`, and could use it on gradle:

```
android {
    …
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs true
        }
    }
}
```

What does it do?

Comment: I guess `This tool iterates over PNG filters and Deflate parameters, using each combination of filters and parameters to compress the image. It then chooses the configuration that yields the smallest compressed output.`

Comment: Stating the [documentations](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html),  
This `aapt` tool can optimize the image resources placed in res/drawable/ with lossless compression during the build process. For example, the aapt tool can convert a true-color PNG that does not require more than 256 colors to an 8-bit PNG with a color palette. Doing so results in an image of equal quality but a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

PNG crunching is now a BuildType property and is disabled by default on debug builds.
**Note**: crunching is basically used for png images filter

Answer (score 0):

It is related to **automatic image compression** base on :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#disable_crunching

Answer (score 0):

By setting crunchPngs property to true reduces of PNG resources that are not already optimally compressed. However, this process increases build times.

PNG crunching is enabled by default in the release build type and disabled by default in the debug build type.
Ref from official doc

https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationBuildType#iscrunchpngs